# How to install MS Surface SDK having VS 2013 Express

Tags: visual-studio-2013, pixelsense

I have VS 2013 Express, and I need to install MS Surface 2.0 SDK. Installer gives a very informative error, exactly:

"you must install the c# project feature for microsoft visual studio 2010 before you install microsoft surface 2.0 sdk"

Can anybody tell me what that error means, and why it needs VS 2010?
I'm using VS 2013 Express.

Comment: Check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21712201/115272) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25074521/115272) apply to you.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it myself yet but heres a link which might point you in the right direction: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21702121/how-to-install-microsoft®-surface®-2-0-sdk-without-installing-visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21702121/how-to-install-microsoft%C2%AE-surface%C2%AE-2-0-sdk-without-installing-visual-studio)

Look at the post by Stéphane Barizien